# SQLite:fts5 and rank, sort by date

Tags: sqlite, fts5

We're using SQLite and FTS5 in our appliction. It's working well and is extremely fast.
However, we have hit a problem when our virtual fts table grows large. We need to sort our search results by date in reverse chronological order and not by the default rank and also limit to 100.
In English, we need the 100 most recent rows that match a search string.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ft USING fts5(time_stamp, data);
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('1', 'foo 1');
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('2', 'foo 2');
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('3', 'foo 3');
SELECT * FROM ft WHERE data MATCH ('foo*') ORDER BY Rank LIMIT 2;
```

The results from the above query look like:

```
-----------------
|time_stamp|data
-----------------
|1         |foo 1
-----------------
|2         |foo 2
-----------------
```

And you can see, the rank is the same for all enteries and the default sort (after Rank) is by date.
Is there a way to use fts5 to sort by reverse date and completely ignore Rank?

What I have below works ... but has terrible performace implications once the table grows large.

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE ft USING fts5(time_stamp, data);
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('1', 'foo 1');
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('2', 'foo 2');
INSERT INTO ft(time_stamp, data) VALUES('3', 'foo 3');
SELECT * FROM ft WHERE data MATCH ('foo*') ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 2;
```

The results from the above query look like:

```
-----------------
|time_stamp|data
-----------------
|3         |foo 3
-----------------
|2         |foo 2
-----------------
```

This is exactly what we're looking for ... but we need a way to achieve it without using the sort on time_stamp

Comment: "When we do this, we use an INNJER JOIN..." please show that as a MRE as described in the wiki info on the first tag you used.

Comment: I've edited my original post

Comment: Please show a MRE as described in the wiki info on the first tag you used. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info I.e. please read it, make an [mre] which includes a few lines of `creat table ...` and `insert ...`.

Comment: Very sorry @Yunnosch. I'll fix

Comment: So, your requirement is: *sort as it would be sorted by time_stamp but without the use of the time_stamp*?

Comment: @forpas - exactly. Sort by date the row was created ... last created row first

It's possible to use the time_stamp column but it really slows the query down when the tables grows

Comment: Would "Custom Auxiliary Functions" do what I want and use this custom function to change the Rank?

Answer (score 1):

If I use ROWID, I get the desired result.

```
SELECT ROWID, time_stamp, data FROM ft WHERE data MATCH ('foo*') ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 2;
```

```
-----------------------
|rowid|time_stamp|data
-----------------------
|3    |3         |foo 3
-----------------------
|2    |2         |foo 2
-----------------------
```

Is it OK to use ROWID?

Comment: The values in the column ROWID may be reused after deletions and insertions. So it is  not guaranteed that the max ROWID belongs to the last inserted row in the table.

Comment: Yes, use autoincrement.